# Actionscript 3 mouse_over play movie, mouse_out reverse movie

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse, mouseevent

I'm trying to make some flash buttons with a mouse_over animation that plays in reverse on mouse_out. Now I have it working for one of my three movie clip instances.

I am using e.currentTarget.play() instead of having a function for each movie clip, but how do I do the same for my playReverse function? I tried putting e.currentTarget.prevFrame() instead of mc1.prevFrame() but it did not work. My code is as follows:

```
mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mover);
mc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mover);
mc3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mover);
mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mout);
mc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mout);
mc3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mout);

function mover(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stopPlayReverse();
    e.currentTarget.play();
}

function mout(e:MouseEvent):void {
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playReverse, false, 0, true);
}

function playReverse(e:Event):void {
    if (mc1.currentFrame == 1) {
        stopPlayReverse();
    } else {
        mc1.prevFrame();
    }
}

function stopPlayReverse():void {
    if (this.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME)) {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playReverse);
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function playReverse only use mc1 how can it work with the others movie clip.

If you choose to do it that way you can keep a track of the current `MovieClip` playing in reverse.
You will have to add more logic if you want that the play in reverse always finish when passing over one clip to another.

```
var currentMovieClip:MovieClip=null;

function mout(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip; 
    if (mc !== null) {
     currentMovieClip = mc;
     this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playReverse, false, 0, true);
    }
}

function playReverse(e:Event):void {
    if (currentMovieClip==null) {
       return;
    }

    if (currentMovieClip.currentFrame == 1) {
        stopPlayReverse();
    } else {
        currentMovieClip.prevFrame();
    }
}
```

Another way that implies that you can have each clip to finish their play in reverse

```
function mover(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stopPlayReverse(e.currentTarget as MovieClip);
    e.currentTarget.play();
}

function mout(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip; 
    if (mc !== null) {
     mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playReverse, false, 0, true);
    }
}

function playReverse(e:Event):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip; 

    if (mc.currentFrame == 1) {
        stopPlayReverse(mc);
    } else {
        mc.prevFrame();
    }
}

function stopPlayReverse(mc:MovieClip):void {
  if ((mc!==null) && mc.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME)) {
    mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playReverse);
  }
}
```